# Using the REST API, how can I tell that a user has blocked OAuth access vs revoked OAuth access?

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, oauth, rest

It seems that I get the same authentication error message the token is invalid. Is there a way I can tell the difference as the vendor?

Note that I am not referring to an Apex app. My app is purely using the web REST API and standard objects/fields.